# Jquery replace div with javascript var

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So basically i have this div in my index page:

```
<div id="title">
      <h1>
        Sala
        <small>Ambiente Controlado</small>
      </h1>
    </div>
```

And then i have this javascript script that will post some data from a form, to another page:

```
      <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function(){
    $('.clsPostData').click(function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
          $('#formsala').hide();
          $('#form').show();
          var objPost = {};
          objPost.local = $(this).data('local');
          objPost.oxiid = $(this).data('oxiid');
          objPost.oxikey = $(this).data('oxikey');
          objPost.redoxid = $(this).data('redoxid');
          objPost.redoxkey = $(this).data('redoxkey');
          var htmlstring = $(this).data('local'); 
          $.ajax({
             url: 'getObjects.php',
             type: 'post',
             dataType: 'text',
             data: objPost
          }).done(function(responseFromPhp){
             //Do something with the response, like
             $('#title').html("<div id='title'><h1>" + htmlstring + "</div></h1>");
          });

    });

});
      </script>
```

The `var htmlstring = $(this).data('local');` is already getting the info i want too, since on click it will get all that info, and post to the "getObjects.php" file, but once the post is done, i want to replace my "title" div with this info...

The script i have is not working, the div "title" isn't being replace by what i have on `.html("<div id='title'><h1>" + htmlstring + "</div></h1>");`

Can someone help me out? Thanks :)

Also my `var htmlstring` is like `"Name 1 - Name 2"`

How can i split this 2 variables into 2? So i can have `<h1>Name 1</h1>` and `<small>Name 2</small>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace

```
$('#title').html("<div id='title'><h1>" + htmlstring + "</div></h1>");
```

with

```
var parts = htmlstring.split(' - ');
$('#title h1').html(parts[0] + '<small>'+parts[1]+'</small>');
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you see the edit please? @Zaur Amikishiyev i have another small problem

Comment: In my answer I assume the small tag is inside the h1 tag as in your html snippet above.

Comment: Thanks, this is exacly what i wanted! @Zaur Amikishiyev